# Подключение к бд из андроид приложения

Tags: android, база-данных

Как вынести бд в интернет и работать с ним из андроид приложения? И возможно ли это с sqlite?

Comment: советую смотреть в сторону spring boot + json.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Да, это возможно.

То, что вы описали делается примерно так:

1. Берётся сервер (арендуется VPS у хостера)
2. На сервер ставится нужная программа (в данном случае SQLite)
3. В настройках оной прописывается разрешение на доступ из вне.
4. В приложение встраивается драйвер для работы с нужной БД.
5. В параметрах подключения к БД с использованием драйвера указывается IP адрес (домен) сервера из п1, порт для подключения к БД (из настроек в п3), имя БД и пароль к ней (также настраиваются на сервере в настройках программы БД).
6. Как только подключение установлено вы можете делать запросы к БД.

Но описанный выше путь - неправильный и опасный и неудобный. Неправильный - т.к. клиентское приложение не должно иметь полный доступ в удалённую БД. Опасный, т.к. адрес и логин-пароль от БД будут передаваться по сети и подвержены перехвату. Неудобный, т.к. вместо привычного общения с сервером в виде `HTTP` запросов в формате `JSON` вы будете писать-получать `SQL`. И если потом вы захотите заменить реализацию БД на что-то другое (а вы захотите, т.к. `Lite` значит обрезанная, например, сделать миграцию схемы для обновления `Nullability` колонки можно лишь скопировав все данные целевой таблицы во временную, удалив текущую и переименовав её, вместо простого изменения свойства колонки как во множестве полноценных БД), то придётся править запросы с одного диалекта на другой.

Правильный путь - обернуть БД на сервере в `REST-API`. Т.е. создать приложение которое будет работать на сервере, принимать запросы из интернета, делать запросы в БД и отдавать обратно `JSON` с информацией из БД.
Тут можно, например, использовать `Spring`. Да, этот вариант долгий и сложный. Зато решает означенные выше проблемы и является `более правильным`.