# Связь Андроида и БД

Tags: android

Я занимаюсь разработкой приложения в Android Studio на языке Java. Я делаю это первый раз. Передо мной стоит задача получения данных в приложении из базы данных размещённой на хостинге. Я пробовал присоединяться через запрос из приложения к php скрипту на сайте, но ни один интернет код у меня не работает.

Скажите, какие альтернативы кроме скрипта php с сайта можно использовать для решения подобной задачи?

Comment: JDBC. Гугл в помощь, как использовать MySQL БД работая с Java. Слишком общий вопрос

Comment: «ни один интернет код у меня не работает» — вот лучше бы рассказали, что у вас с интернет-кодом не получается. У тысяч существующих приложений всё работает ведь, значит у вас должно работать

Comment: android studio - среда разработки, одна из нескольких и акцентировать на ней вопрос, если он не относится к **именно ее работе** не нужно. Ваш вопрос можно решить в любой IDE с одинаковым успехом и ставить теги Android Studio не надо.

Comment: @Dizzy221 для работу с удаленной бд желательно не использовать jdbc, а писать веб-сервис

Comment: Возможно вам будет вот это полезно: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/947269/17609 Ну и да - покажите код - так будет проще понять что у вас не так.