# Отправить запрос к Postgre и получить ответ

Tags: android, postgresql

Не могу разобраться, как организовать обмен информацией между приложением на android и БД postgresql.
Нахожу достаточно много информации о MySQL и  MSSQL, но только не postgresql.

Comment: Вне зависимости от используемой БД лучше всего делать прослойку в виде серверного кода, который обращается к БД, а с приложением взаимодействует через API, например REST через HTTP

Comment: Mike, а можно приблизительно на пальцах объяснить как это должно выглядеть? Я поднимаю веб сервер например апач и взаимодействую через него или как-то по другому?

Comment: Да, запрос идет на web сервер. тот передает его обработчику cgi, например коду на php, который уже лезет в базу

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/947235/Подключение-к-бд-из-андроид-приложения/947269#947269